# How should you distribute the fighting power?

Tags: mathematics, probability, game

Alice and Bob both have N warriors under their command, numbered 1~N, and $1$ point of fighting power at their disposal. Before the game, they privately distribute the power between their warriors. When the game begins, both send their warrior #1 to a 1v1 fight. If a warrior with power x fights one with power y, the former wins with probability $\frac{x}{x+y}$, and the latter with probability $\frac{y}{x+y}$. If #1 is defeated, #2 is sent to continue the next round of fight, so on and so forth until one party has all of their warriors defeated and loses the game. **The more battles a warrior wins, the stronger he becomes: after a warrior defeats an $x$ power opponent, his power will increase by $\frac{x}{2}$.** Both players want to maximize their winning probabilities.

How should Alice distribute her fighting power?

Comment: The game is symmetric with respect to the two players. This is like asking what is the best strategy for playing rock-paper-scissors.

Comment: @WhatsUp I guess in this case it would still be interesting to prove that "whatever strategy Alice chooses, the probabiilty of winning is still the same, which is 0.5" and not that some strategy is losing. I agree that the best strategy will have 0.5 probability of winning, due to symmetry. EDIT: Jaap put it better than me.

Comment: @WhatsUp From the symmetry you only know that their probabilities of winning are both 50% if they play optimally. That does not mean that the optimal strategy is obvious. It is likely that the optimal [Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium) is a mixed strategy, involving randomly choosing between various scenarios, just like rock-paper-scissors, but finding the worthwhile scenarios and their probabilities can be complicated.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, yeah, I tried calculating the optimal strategy for N=2, but I must have mistake somewhere since the best strategy does not have 0.5 probability. So it's not that simple indeed (or I did it in a too complicated way)

Comment: @WhatsUp https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2F%28x%2By%29%29+%281+-+%281-y%29%281%2B0.5x-0.75y%29%2F%28%281%2Bx-0.5y%29%282-0.5x-0.75y%29%29%29+%2B+%28y%2F%28x%2By%29%29+%28%281-x%29%281-0.75x%2B0.5y%29%2F%28%281-0.5x%2By%29%282-0.75x-0.5y%29%29%29%3B+x%3D0+to+1%3B+y%3D0+to+1 here is the probability space for N=2. X is the probability Alice put in her first warrior, Y is for Bob. We see that there is some choice that leads to sub-optimal result.

Comment: What happens if 2 warriors facing eachother have 0 power. The probability for each winning is (0 / 0+0). Does this means they both have 50% chance of winning or we divide by 0 and the universe implodes?

Comment: And another question. You can distribute 1 point in total? I mean each warrior gets sub-unitary power and all of them should add to 1, or the total number of power points is N?

Comment: Total points should be 1, so 0.8+0.1+0.1 is a valid distribution for 3 units. And 0 vs 0 case won't happen.

Comment: "0 vs 0 case won't happen" - Sure it can, if both initial warriors have no power. It is true that you can't reach a 0-vs-0 scenario unless you're in one already, though.

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, we need to handle that edge case too. Any advice, OP? @Eric. At first glance I guess it should be 50:50

Comment: @justhalf Doesn't matter. If 0 vs 0 happens, assign any ratio as you like. No matter who wins, it will not affect the outcome a bit.

Comment: Oh, that's right too, as both will go to the next fighter anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Some semi-stochastic simulations with sample size 100 and N = 2, 3, and 4 tell me that the optimal strategy consists of

> starting with *weaker* units in front, with power gradually (and roughly linearly) increasing towards the rear.

Some strong contenders:

> [.421,.578], as in justhalf's comment.
>  [.25,.33,.42] and [.3,.3,.4]
>  [.11,.26,.26,.37], [.175, .2, .275, .35], and [.1,.2,.3,.4]

You can [play around online here](https://tio.run/##dVM9k5swEO35FTtHEWS4YFw648JOkTYzuU5DIYOwdQcSI8nxOH/eWUmANffhxmjf2933VqvxZs9Kbu73TqsBhOXaKtUbEMOotIVGDUchmRVKmsRTNJOtYwZ8OjHjv5KWd3DkzJqM9aLhxVEdyRbSn6xvLj2zHHz4m4GrkBrPCeBPdCCVDdAWNLcXLWEdQ1hmASoP7GEXEui6/gEHPCEHvz04MbP9Kmih@/xQbuo8JFTb2uly/yQ/rCK5HqL7cpMf6nymkDLDdJJ4b1ZhYTZwaTOmT8Z520PLcWqDkMJY0USU2UHPZWDDbgfVYsSFPMU0SvOjYrpFGwanytuMUnMZMhrEieKVQKc0vIIIeTUpRO1D4hGKvUdC6RutAvfNcR/d6CKsLDfbup48ekLWKGm5sUzaYnb6u2c3YGCEPPUcLGd47ycmpMG7gx7dg@pA2TPXHjSxnshNVPmjrXLRFMQwjXt14pl0An5xybXfIviLF9YGDdhUwhWJQum554CycJhhV0Z1RUk7oGE7lqlNlZ8rsvWAT0We2@SMLCGf/p2NI8dwKL3SD3hqtsJuzzq27PNyGvA6SdI0hRc1vZj@BqfZDb4FiTMNQyvgIvHR@f1JnQeBVyjkeLHZ04uz@0f8w1fyREiSvnNSrdFI6hRMI3aeHwOED/T1mtQhYdSuTbQ0UwXsMuv2awE3pIC6yk/EXs8C16KaJMwX4jR0vWJoIlIQGXJe6i9lu3WYS5FPLbzzELZ3TikePu73/w) - further runs at higher sample sizes with teams of all kinds shows that it's actually pretty easy to get above even against [uniformly] random teams, but hard to get a winrate of .52 or above.

> Just don't let any one warrior be too weak.

Comment: Do you find it plausible that there's a single best distribution of power, in the sense that it will guarantee you no less than 50% winning probability for **every** possible team of your opponent?

Comment: I find it yes for 2 warriors. Are you trying to imply that that's not the case?

Comment: I believe Eric's question is a general statement about all N. "Fitness" seems simple enough that it should have a single global maximum, but I wouldn't be so bold as to say it will be winning against every other team.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proof, but a gut feeling that the optimal strategy is to

> Put all power to the first warrior

Because

> Concerning resources, you only have 1 + win bonuses. Earlier wins = earlier resources. If Bob does not follow the same tactic, RNG aside, he will be practically be "feeding" Alice's monster.

Comment: I thought of this too, but surprisingly, even for 2 warriors, this is false. If both put all power in the first warrior, Alice wins with probability 0.5, this is clear. But if Bob puts all power in the first warrior and Alice puts 0.8 power on the first warrior, Bob wins only if he won both, which has the probability 1/1.8 * 1.4/1.6 = 5/9 * 7/8 = 35/72 = 0.49. So Alice has better chance to win. I guess the intuition is that putting all on the first warrior means you lose immediately once you lose that warrior, while Alice has 2 chances.

Comment: Or maybe it doesn't prove that it's false, since perhaps over all possible Alice's choice, the expectation of winning is still 0.5 with any strategy. But my point is that it's not that simple to prove.

Comment: @justhalf Interesting, the total opposite tactic of equal spreading point makes bob win 0.0001% times

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2F%28x%2By%29%29+%281+-+%281-y%29%281%2B0.5x-0.75y%29%2F%28%281%2Bx-0.5y%29%282-0.5x-0.75y%29%29%29+%2B+%28y%2F%28x%2By%29%29+%28%281-x%29%281-0.75x%2B0.5y%29%2F%28%281-0.5x%2By%29%282-0.75x-0.5y%29%29%29%3B+x%3D0+to+1%3B+y%3D0+to+1

That's the whole probability space for N=2. Seems like the optimal strategy is to spread it evenly.

Comment: @justhalf There's even a better strategy than to spread evenly.

Comment: Yeah, the graph does show that evenly is not the best, but the optimal is very close to it.